# After using Boot-Repair I cannot change screen resolution

Tags: resolution

After I tried to install Windows on my 500 GB HDD, where Ubuntu is already installed,  the installation rebooted at 1%. Then I got a black screen: no grub, no nothing.

I had to use the live CD to be able ask for help. I was told to use Boot-Repair. I did and recovered grub, but the screen resolution is set too low (1024x768 max), I cannot change it.

The system is recognized as a laptop and my monitor is an LG E1941S. I do not have an dedicated graphics card (Nvidia, AMD, etc).

Comment: try this instead of nomodeset at grub menu. press e for edit, scroll to linux line and add after quiet splash. This is just a one time change to test.  video=1366x768-24@60

Comment: Hello oldfred and thank you very much. It worked. When I reboot it came back the bad resolution, then I think I have to erase "This is just a one time change to test". Am I right?

Comment: You can permanently add setting in grub.  gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub - Change to add it after splash quiet. Then run sudo update-grub to make change in grub menu permanent.

Comment: Hi oldfred, I make what you said and it works definitely. I've shut down computer and re-start and everything is ok. Thank you again. Regards from Argentina :-)

Comment: Since it worked I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @user299596 accept oldfred's answer if your problem got solved... It will usefull to others may have same problem..

Answer (score 1):

To test if setting screen resolution works, you can edit the grub menu entry similar to a nomodeset entry.

Press e for edit, scroll to linux line and add after or replace quiet splash with your correct video X by Y setting like:

```
video=1366x768-24@60
```

If that works or whatever setting does work you can add it to grub to make it permanent. Each reboot and edit of grub as you boot is a one time change.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

Add it to the same line as the quiet splash setting you currently have:

GRUB_CMD_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

Should be this?

GRUB_CMD_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=1366x768-24@60"